# Creating exam answers with check marks

Tags: exam, box

I am trying to put an example of an exam key in the main body of an article. Because of this I am using the document style "article" (maybe it is not good idea but I am not sure how to use different document classes within the same document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here I put some description.

\begin{section}*{Test questions}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Who is guilty?

\hspace{7mm} \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.9em}} Person A

\hspace{7mm} \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$} Person B

\hspace{7mm} \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.9em}} Person C

\hspace{7mm} \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.9em}} Person D

\hspace{7mm} \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.9em}} Person E

    \item What to do?
\end{enumerate}


\end{section}   
\end{document}
```

Is there a more elegant way to put the options?
Also, I want a check mark to be in red color. How to do that?

Comment: If you really want elegance, use the eforms package (\checkBox page 9).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is more elegant but here is a solution that uses the `exam` class with some customizations to get something closer to the OP output:

```
\documentclass[12pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\checkboxchar{$\square$}
\checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\itemindent}{3mm}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test questions}
\begin{questions}


\question Who is guilty?


\begin{checkboxes}

\choice Person A
\correctchoice Person B
\choice Person C
\choice Person D
\choice Person E

\end{checkboxes}

\question What to do ?
\end{questions}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Checkmark}{\textcolor{red}{$\checkmark$}}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

Here I put some description.

\begin{section}*{Test questions}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Who is guilty?
\begin{itemize}\fboxsep=1pt %gap between box and contents
\item[\fbox{\phantom{\Checkmark}}] Person A
\item[\fbox{\Checkmark}] Person B
\item[\fbox{\phantom{\Checkmark}}] Person C
\item[\fbox{\phantom{\Checkmark}}] Person D
\item[\fbox{\phantom{\Checkmark}}] Person E
\end{itemize}
    \item What to do?
\end{enumerate}

\end{section}   
\end{document}
```

---

With some help from [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616829/does-eforms-have-an-equivalent-to-hyperref-forms-option-checked) I was able to create an eforms version.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eforms}

\newsavebox{\squarebox}
\savebox{\squarebox}{$\square$}% default size

\everyRadioButton{
\BC{0 0 0}% black
\BG{1 1 1}% white
\textColor{1 0 0}% red
%\symbolchoice{check}% default
}
\begin{document}

%\maketitle

Here I put some description.

\begin{section}*{Test questions}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Who is guilty?
\begin{itemize}\fboxsep=1pt %gap between box and contents
\item[{\radioButton[\V{B}]{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{A}}] Person A
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{B}] Person B
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{C}] Person C
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{D}] Person D
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{E}] Person E
\end{itemize}
    \item What to do?
\end{enumerate}

\end{section}   
\end{document}
```