# Does eforms have an equivalent to hyperref forms option checked?

Tags: hyperref, eforms

I'm trying to preset one of the radio buttons on.  So far nothing I have tried has worked.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eforms}

\everyRadioButton{
\BC{0 0 0}% black
\BG{1 1 1}% white
\textColor{1 0 0}% red
%\symbolchoice{check}% default
}
\begin{document}

%\maketitle

Here I put some description.

\begin{section}*{Test questions}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Who is guilty?
\begin{itemize}\fboxsep=1pt %gap between box and contents
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{A}] Person A
\item[{\radioButton[\DV{B}]{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{B}}] Person B
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{C}] Person C
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{D}] Person D
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{E}] Person E
\end{itemize}
    \item What to do?
\end{enumerate}

\end{section}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the value that should be checked in the first radiobutton:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eforms}

\everyRadioButton{
\BC{0 0 0}% black
\BG{1 1 1}% white
\textColor{1 0 0}% red
\symbolchoice{check}% default
}
\begin{document}



\begin{enumerate}
    \item Who is guilty?
\begin{itemize}\fboxsep=1pt %gap between box and contents
\item[{\radioButton[\V{B}]{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{A}}] Person A
\item[{\radioButton[\DV{B}]{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{B}}] Person B
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{C}] Person C
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{D}] Person D
\item[\radioButton{Q1}{10bp}{10bp}{E}] Person E
\end{itemize}
    \item What to do?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]