# Multiple choice questions with hints about how many choices are expected (single vs multiple)

Tags: environments, conditionals, exam

I use paper exams (with LaTeX) for midterms and finals, but I also use LMS quizzes for learning the material. As such, my students are used to Moodle, where if a multiple choice question is intended to have more than one correct answer, it's displayed with checkboxes:

[image: check box capture]

If a single answer is expected, it has radio buttons:

[image: radio button capture] (option c has been chosen in this example).

Is there a way to get this automatically in exam.cls? That is, if an multiple choice question has more than one `\correctanswer` I'd like the choices to be shown with check boxes. Otherwise, use round circles (radio buttons).

> Edit after John Kormylo's comment: `\checkboxchar{$\Box$}` and `\checkboxchar{$\bigcirc$}` are described in the documentation for exam.cls. The question is whether or not it's possible to define some dynamic code ([conditionals](/questions/tagged/conditionals)) to set these values each time a `\begin{checkboxes}` or `\begin{oneparcheckboxes}` is encountered. That is, if there's more than one `\correctanswer` in the environment, the character should be a box; otherwise it's a circle. In fact, I'm generating the LaTeX from GIFT questions, so perhaps I can do this in the code generator.

It's quite tedious and not so user-friendly to have to write in the question: "Select the best answer" (for one) or "Select the best answers" (for many).

Maybe there's another solution to the problem that doesn't require checkboxes and radio buttons?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616740/creating-exam-answers-with-check-marks